# MS Graph Webhook report new email that doesn't exist

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a multi-tenant application that has webhooks setup to monitor for new emails arriving in the `SentItems` folder. Sometimes I get a notification for a random tenant, that a new email has arrived, but I can't find it in the user's mailbox through Microsoft Graph or EWS.

I get a notification that this ID has arrived:

```
AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK3wAAAA==
```

but the only messages in the `SentItems` folder are these:

```
[0]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK6wAAAA=="
[1]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK6gAAAA=="
[2]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK6QAAAA=="
[3]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK6AAAAA=="
[4]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK5wAAAA=="
[5]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK5AAAAA=="
[6]: "AAMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAAAAAAnaThn6c3YR6wA5CaaALt2BwD45xsfmmj8TKVOa3R-3Ss0AAAAAAEJAAD45xsfmmj8TKVOa3R-3Ss0AAA9xTdMAAA="
[7]: "AAMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAAAAAAnaThn6c3YR6wA5CaaALt2BwD45xsfmmj8TKVOa3R-3Ss0AAAAAAEJAAD45xsfmmj8TKVOa3R-3Ss0AAAHDRc_AAA="
[8]: "AQMkAGE1YmY5ZTM3LTdhYjYtNGU2MS05MDJkLWQzMDgxNDZlN2EwMQBGAAADJ2k4Z_nN2EesAOQmmgC7dgcA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAgEJAAAA_OcbH5po-EylTmt0f90rNAAAAQOK1wAAAA=="
```

and the email is not to be found anywhere in the mailbox. I actually think it's strange that two of the IDs don't match the parent folder's ID, but the rest do.

UPDATE 04/07:

Mark requested the complete notification, but I don't have it for this ID. Hovever I got a new one, where the item does not exist. The notification was part of multiple, but the one that I can't find is this one:

```
{  
     "subscriptionId":"70f45211-1096-4282-b34a-b37219ff7756",
     "subscriptionExpirationDateTime":"2018-07-04T23:00:02.7089152+00:00",
     "changeType":"created",
     "resource":"Users/2e1b31b1-9ba8-43b0-92e2-d7e7eb740017/Messages/AAMkADZhMWJhNjQ3LTJkZGQtNGViYS05MTBlLWExYzg1YWU4YjU1OABGAAAAAAC0KduT98_pQLvg9lqbswvNBwCXszCEea-1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAAAAAAEJAACXszCEea-1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAAAAH3cQAAA=",
     "resourceData":{  
        "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Graph.Message",
        "@odata.id":"Users/2e1b31b1-9ba8-43b0-92e2-d7e7eb740017/Messages/AAMkADZhMWJhNjQ3LTJkZGQtNGViYS05MTBlLWExYzg1YWU4YjU1OABGAAAAAAC0KduT98_pQLvg9lqbswvNBwCXszCEea-1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAAAAAAEJAACXszCEea-1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAAAAH3cQAAA=",
        "@odata.etag":"W/\"CQAAABYAAACXszCEea/1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAABTkl6J\"",
        "id":"AAMkADZhMWJhNjQ3LTJkZGQtNGViYS05MTBlLWExYzg1YWU4YjU1OABGAAAAAAC0KduT98_pQLvg9lqbswvNBwCXszCEea-1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAAAAAAEJAACXszCEea-1T5Fvw2GeYIEvAAAAH3cQAAA="
     },
     "clientState":"e698cb6b-03f6-4ecb-847d-aa142a21176d"
  },
```

UPDATE 05-07:
Another one:

```
{  
     "subscriptionId":"3f7f0518-1e1c-4126-b046-ead9251692e8",
     "subscriptionExpirationDateTime":"2018-07-06T19:00:11.8955691+00:00",
     "changeType":"created",
     "resource":"Users/dcfcac62-511b-425c-93ad-e7f786f67f90/Messages/AAMkADdjMzk2ZmE5LWFhZTgtNDY4MC04NTQ3LWQ1NTc1N2FhYWU5OQBGAAAAAADHkc19ugpQQYziYaUQfoyOBwB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAAAAAEJAAB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAMSo0tHAAA=",
     "resourceData":{  
        "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Graph.Message",
        "@odata.id":"Users/dcfcac62-511b-425c-93ad-e7f786f67f90/Messages/AAMkADdjMzk2ZmE5LWFhZTgtNDY4MC04NTQ3LWQ1NTc1N2FhYWU5OQBGAAAAAADHkc19ugpQQYziYaUQfoyOBwB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAAAAAEJAAB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAMSo0tHAAA=",
        "@odata.etag":"W/\"CQAAABYAAAB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAMTQCkA\"",
        "id":"AAMkADdjMzk2ZmE5LWFhZTgtNDY4MC04NTQ3LWQ1NTc1N2FhYWU5OQBGAAAAAADHkc19ugpQQYziYaUQfoyOBwB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAAAAAEJAAB4OcB73fiVTK3E3hTiQwPfAAMSo0tHAAA="
     },
     "clientState":"59f393b1-6200-4c4e-9ce3-7d70a009359c"
  }
```

Comment: Can you include the complete webhook message? There is more to it than just the ID itself.

Comment: I'll need to change the code and deploy, to log the complete request. I'll get back to you

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Any news on this issue?

Comment: These looking messages in the `inbox`, not the `sentItems` folder. How is your subscription set up?

Comment: I'm using the graph sdk for c# and using the method MailFolders["SentItems"].Messages.Request().RequestUrl on IUserRequestBuilder to get the resource url, which is '/users/xxxx@xxxxx.xx/mailFolders/SentItems/messages'. This works for most parts, but as mentioned sometimes the id does not exist, neither via Graph or EWS

Comment: Normally, when the `id` doesn't exist, it is because the message got moved. Typically this occurs when the user receives a push notification on their device and instantly clicks "delete" or "archive". Often times this occurs before your backend has had the opportunity to receive the notification, process it, and fetch the message. I'll admit to being a bit baffled how this occurs with `SentItems` since most users don't move messages out of that folder.

Comment: It's possible some other process (i.e. a CRM monitoring the mailbox) could be moving the message which would explain why this acts like a race condision.  That feels like a stretch but it's worth investigating just to rule it out.

Comment: Given that mobile devices increase the changes of the state/id of an object changing  so easily, I normally advise against using the `id` directly from the webhook. A better approch is to use `/deltas` to retrieve all of the messages in the folder that have arrived since your last poll. The webhook then becomes simply a trigger to fire off the `/delta` workflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's seems you were right [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur). It was due to messages being moved from the sentItems folder. The user archived the email manually in my system, and moved the email to another folder, to indicate that it was archived. Strange behavior :)